# buildroot error when compiling wpa_supplicant

Tags: buildroot, wpa

I've got an error while building wpa_supplicant with buildroot

```
home@debian-host:/build/buildroot# make
>>> wpa_supplicant 2.6 Building
PATH="/build/buildroot/output/host/bin:/build/buildroot/output/host/sbin:/build/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin:/build/buildroot/output/host/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" CFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  -I/build/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-astrokitpi3-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/libnl3/" LDFLAGS="" BINDIR=/usr/sbin LIBS="" LIBS_c="" LIBS_p="" /usr/bin/make -j5 CC="/build/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-astrokitpi3-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" -C /build/buildroot/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.6/wpa_supplicant
make[1]: Entering directory '/build/buildroot/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.6/wpa_supplicant'
../src/common/sae.o : Dans la fonction « sae_cn_confirm.isra.2 » :
sae.c:(.text+0x15c) : référence indéfinie vers « crypto_bignum_to_bin »
sae.c:(.text+0x18c) : référence indéfinie vers « crypto_bignum_to_bin »
../src/common/sae.o : Dans la fonction « sae_cn_confirm_ffc » :
...
...
sae.c:(.text+0x1c44) : référence indéfinie vers « crypto_bignum_cmp »
sae.c:(.text+0x1c64) : référence indéfinie vers « crypto_ec_point_cmp »
collect2: erreur : ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
Makefile:1689: recipe for target 'wpa_supplicant' failed
make[1]: *** [wpa_supplicant] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/buildroot/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.6/wpa_supplicant'
package/pkg-generic.mk:216: recipe for target '/build/buildroot/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.6/.stamp_built' failed
make: *** [/build/buildroot/output/build/wpa_supplicant-2.6/.stamp_built] Error 2
```

any idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please select the OpenSSL package in "Target packages > Libraries > Crypto".

Comment: Thanks, i will try. Stef